# Best way to implement a pageable to Angular Project

Tags: html, angular, typescript, web, frontend

I have products in my database and I have created controller on my backend app that I tested and works really good, so now I need to implement that to my frontend. I have product.component.ts file that looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { debounceTime, switchMap } from "rxjs";
import { ProductService } from "./product.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-product',
    templateUrl: './product.component.html'
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

    products: any[] = [];
    productSearchForm!: FormGroup;
    page: number = 0;
    size: number = 4;

    constructor(
        private productService: ProductService
    ) { }

    loadMore() {
        this.page = this.page+1;

        this.productSearchForm.get('searchTerm')?.valueChanges
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(500),
                switchMap(value => {
                    return this.productService.searchByTermPageable(value, this.page, this.size);
                })
            ).subscribe(data => {
                this.products = data;
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                // this.products = [];
            });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initializeForm();

        this.productSearchForm.get('searchTerm')?.valueChanges
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(500),
                switchMap(value => {
                    return this.productService.searchByTermPageable(value, this.page, this.size);
                })
            ).subscribe(data => {
                this.products = data;
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                // this.products = [];
            });
    }

    private initializeForm(): void {
        this.productSearchForm = new FormGroup({
            searchTerm: new FormControl(null)
        });
    }
}
```

searchTerm is a query param that is used to find products with name starting with that term. I call function from file product.service.ts that looks like this

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class ProductService {

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

   searchByTerm(searchTerm: string): Observable<any> {
       const url = `${environment.apiUrl}product/search/by-name-or-desc?term=${searchTerm}`;
       return this.httpClient.get(url);
   }

   searchByTermPageable(searchTerm: string, page: number, size: number): Observable<any> {
       const url = `${environment.apiUrl}product/search/by-name-or-desc?term=${searchTerm}&page=${page}&size=${size}`;
       return this.httpClient.get(url);
   }

}
```

When I click the button load more I want to load next 4 products from database, but keep the first 4 products on my html page, so what is the best way to do this? This is my html page, and also I am using Bulma as my css framework

```
<div class="mt-5">
    <form>
        <div class="field" [formGroup]="productSearchForm">
            <div class="control has-icons-left">
                <input class="input" type="text" formControlName="searchTerm" placeholder="Find products">
                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </form>
</div>

<div class="columns">
    <div class="column" *ngFor="let product of products">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <p class="title is-4">{{ product.name }}</p>
                        <p class="subtitle is-6">{{ product.category?.name}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    {{ product.description }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="button is-primary" (click)="loadMore()">Load more...</button>
```

Comment: When the data is loaded from the server store them to a list and in side the html file loop through the list to display the data and next time when you want to fetch more data append the new data to the existing list. This way the previously loaded data would remain and the new data will be added to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can to have a new function in your service that return the elements of the page plus the other elements search. If you has a function that return the paginate elements

```
searchByTermPageable(search:string,page:number,size:number)
{
    ...
}
```

Some like

```
  product:any[]=[]  //define an empty array where you store the product
  searchOld:string=null  //and a variable to store the search

  getData(search:string,page:number,size:number)
  {
    if (search!=this.searchOld)  //if is a new search
    {
      this.searchOld=search
      this.product=[]
    }

    return this.searchByTermPageable(search,page,size).pipe(
      map((res:any[])=>[...this.product,...res]), //concat the before store product
      tap((res:any[])=>{
        this.product=res  //store in the product the new array
      })
    )
  }
```

Allow you some like

```
    <div *ngFor="let product of product$|async">
      {{product.name}}
    </div>
    <button (click)="more()">more</button>

  pageIndex:number=-1;
  product$:Observable<any[]>
  more()
  {
    this.pageIndex++
    this.product$=this.dataService.getData("",this.pageIndex,4)
  }
```

The other solution is search all the product and simple use slice pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let product of allProduct$|async |slice:0:(index+1)*pageSize">
{{product.name}}
</div>
<button (click)="index=index+1">more</button>
```

a [litle stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cykxqu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That was really helpful, i could use both ways, my question is just if I use the second method isn't that a little unnecessary memory consuming?